# How do I replace a url param without replace? in Angular

Tags: angular

Sorry if I am a bit new to Angular, but I am encounter an issue.
I am calling some 3rd party api to get some data to construct some sort of chart.

the api looks like this.

```
http://api.e.xyz.com/rc/r/{{ID}}/names
```

if I just do

```
url = 'http://api.e.xyz.com/rc/r/{{ID}}/names';
this.url.replace({{ID}}, '123');
this.httpClient.get(this.url);
...
```

wouldn't that be vulnerable to some sort of injection or security issues?
I wanted to replace {{ID}} with the ID i got. what is the best way going to do this?

I am using Angular 6.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `replace`, just build the string like this:

```
url = `http://api.e.xyz.com/rc/r/${ID}/names`;
```

or this:

```
url = 'http://api.e.xyz.com/rc/r/' + ID + '/names';
```

Your API server side code should also be validating the ID. For example, if it's supposed to be a number, check that it is a number.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mt2anv) create one class model

```
export class Url{
    private static baseUrl="http://api.e.xyz.com/rc/r/";
    public static getChartUrl(param){
       return Url.baseUrl+param+"/names"
    }
}
```

and call in the component like

```
Url.getChartUrl("test")
```